# How can define an acknowledgement section in two languages

Tags: environments, acknowledgements

I am writing my LaTex document and I would like crate an `acknowledgement`section in two languages: first written in my mother tongue (Italian) and then in English as the rest of the document.

I'm using the document class `sapthesis` which creates an acknowledgemens section like in the image below but I can't do what I want.

[image]

The code that I used for this is the following:

```
  \begin{acknowledgments}
     acknowledgments in my mothertongue...and after in english
    \end{acknowledgments}
```

My idea is to create an own environment (named for example `myAcknowledgement`) in which at the top there is a section Ringraziamenti written in Italian and below (in the same page) a similar section `Acknowledgements` written in English.

The `acknowledgements` (in both the tongues) enter in a page.
I would like that after this page, there is a blank page.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would reveal which special package you are using for `acknowledments`? Perhaps you can use your `\begin{acknowledgements}...\end{acknowledgements}` just twice?

Comment: I can't use this twice because it create two different pages named 'Acknowledgemnts' .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a one-off application just use a dirty trick:

```
\documentclass[PhD]{sapthesis}

\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{italian}
\begin{acknowledgments}[Ringraziamenti]
\lipsum*[2]
\end{acknowledgments}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\vspace{3\bigskipamount}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}% just a trick for localizing \cleardoublepage
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\begin{acknowledgments}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{acknowledgments}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An improved version, with a keyvalue interface, for setting `\cleardoublepage` on demand. (Note: `blindtext` will complain about `italian` but that's not really an issue!)

```
\documentclass[PhD]{sapthesis}

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xparse}



\makeatletter
\define@boolkey{sap}{clearpageafter}[true]{%
}

\define@boolkey{sap}{clearpagebefore}[true]{%
}

\newcommand{\SAP@AcknowledgmentsLabelenglish}{Acknowledgments}
\newcommand{\SAP@AcknowledgmentsLabelitalian}{Ringraziamenti}

\presetkeys{sap}{clearpagebefore=true,clearpageafter=true}{}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{acknowledgments}{O{english}D<>{}}{%
  \setkeys{sap}{#2}%

  \ifKV@sap@clearpagebefore
  \cleardoublepage%
  \thispagestyle{empty} 
  \fi%

  \begin{otherlanguage}{#1}%
  \noindent{\Large\bfseries\csname SAP@AcknowledgmentsLabel#1\endcsname}\par\vspace{0.5cm}\itshape\noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
  \end{otherlanguage}%

  \ifKV@sap@clearpageafter
  \cleardoublepage%
  \fi%

  \null\ignorespacesafterend
}



\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{acknowledgments}[italian]<clearpageafter=false>
\blindtext
\end{acknowledgments}

\begin{acknowledgments}<clearpagebefore=false>
\blindtext
\end{acknowledgments}


\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

[image]